# Frame title position for a beamer theme

Tags: beamer, themes, frame-title, sidebar

I am trying to build a `beamer theme`. I would like the `frametitle` to run along the left margin of the `frame`. So I write this MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Title}
\author{John Smith}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}{\insertframenumber}

\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{plain}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\begin{beamercolorbox}[%
      wd=\paperheight,%
      sep=0pt,%
      leftskip=0cm,%
      rightskip=1cm,%
    ]{frametitle}%%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)}]
            \fill[fg] (0,.5ex-1.5pt) rectangle (.1*\paperheight,.5ex+1.5pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
  \insertframetitle%
  \nolinebreak%%
  \hfill
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\usebeamertemplate*{frame numbering}}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[plain]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Frame Title}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following result

[image]

This does not work for two main reasons: (1) the `frametitle` is not exactly on the left margin, but there is some space, (2) the content moves after the `frametitle`. Is there a way to solve these two issues? I prefer not to use `overlay/remember picture`  from `tikz` package.

**WHAT I TRIED**
I tried to modify the `sidebar left` template instead of the `frametitle` template. This approach has some problems: (1) it is overwritten by `\useoutertheme{sidebar}` or at least it overwrites it, it is not placed next to it, (2) the width of the sidebar does not change with the content, a long title might overlap with the content (3) it changes the margin in the `titlepage`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- > (1) the frametitle is not exactly on the left margin, but there is some space

  move the box left by `\beamer@leftmargin`
- > (2) the content moves after the frametitle

  you can make sure that the title box does not occupy vertical space (and thus pushing the frame body down) by smashing the box
- > (2) the width of the sidebar does not change with the content, a long title might overlap with the content

  this is not addressed in the solution below. If you want the frametitle to influence the width of the text area, you might have to rewrite how beamer builds its frames...

  Maybe an easier approach would be to increase the left text margin so that it can fit two lines of frametitle?

Some of the numbers in the code below might need a bit fine tuning...

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Title}
\author{John Smith}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}{\insertframenumber}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{plain}{%
  \hspace{-\beamer@leftmargin}%
  \smash{\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{\begin{beamercolorbox}[%
      wd=\paperheight,%
      sep=0pt,%
      leftskip=0cm,%
      rightskip=0cm,%
      vmode
    ]{frametitle}%%
    \hspace*{0.1em}
    \parbox[t]{.85\linewidth}{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)}]
            \fill[fg] (0,.5ex-1.5pt) rectangle (.1*\paperheight,.5ex+1.5pt);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
  \strut\insertframetitle}%
  \hfill
  \parbox{.1\linewidth}{\hfill\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\usebeamertemplate*{frame numbering}}\hspace{0.35em}\mbox{}}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}}%
  \vskip-1.47em
}
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[plain]




\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Frame Title}
ghds
\end{frame}



\begin{frame}[t]
ghds
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame Title which is terrible long and occupies two line}
ghds
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Frame Title}
ghds
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]